# Group array by unique values of nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Starting from the following array, in JavaScript, using Lodash, how do I group the tasks by unique users, to output the "tasks_by_user" array below?

Input:

```
tasks: [
  {
    name: "buy milk",
    users: [
      "123", "456"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "get bread",
    users: [
      "123"
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
tasks_by_user : [
  {
    user: "123",
    tasks: [
      {
        name: "buy milk"
      },
      {
        name: "get bread"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    user: "456",
    tasks: [
      {
        name: "buy milk"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Everything I've tried (a combination of _,map, _.groupBy, etc.) doesn't work…

Comment: I think you should rethink the organization of your data. What you want to achieve is possible but so complexe

Comment: I don't have a choice about the Input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce` and `forEach` methods.

```js
const data = [{"name":"buy milk","users":["123","456"]},{"name":"get bread","users":["123"]}]

let result = _.values(_.reduce(data, (r, {name,users}) => {
  _.forEach(users, user => {
    if (!r[user]) r[user] = {
      user,
      tasks: []
    }
    r[user].tasks.push({name})
  })
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep! Thanks Nenad. Although I'm getting an extra "key", so I've added a _.map at the end to clean up the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

plain javascript solution.

```
const data = [{
  "name": "buy milk",
  "users": ["123", "456"]
}, {
  "name": "get bread",
  "users": ["123"]
}];

var result = data.reduce((acc, {name, users}) => {
  users.forEach(u => {
    acc[u] = (acc[u] || []);
    acc[u].push(name);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result).map(user => {
  return {
    user,
    tasks: result[user]
  };
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a native [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by grouping the input data by the user id, and then mapping out the grouped object to an array:

```js
const tasks=[{name:"buy milk",users:["123","456"]},{name:"get bread",users:["123"]}];

var dataObj = tasks.reduce((all, {name, users}) => {

  users.forEach(user => {

    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(user)) all[user] = {user, tasks: []};

    all[user].tasks.push({name});

  })

  return all;

}, {});

var tasks_by_user = Object.keys(dataObj).map(k => dataObj[k]);

console.log(tasks_by_user);
```

Answer (score 0):

**@trs**, you can also try the below code.

```
/* Input array */
var tasks = {tasks: [
  {
    name: "buy milk",
    users: [
      "123", "456"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "get bread",
    users: [
      "123"
    ]
  }
]}

var inputArr = tasks['tasks']

/* Creating output array */
var outputArr = []
var outputObj = {}

for(var obj of inputArr){
    for(var user of obj["users"]){
        var o = {'name': obj['name']}

        if(outputObj[user] == undefined){
            outputObj[user] = [o]
        } else {
            outputObj[user].push(o)
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(outputObj, null, 4))
/*
    {
        "123": [
            {
                "name": "buy milk"
            },
            {
                "name": "get bread"
            }
        ],
        "456": [
            {
                "name": "buy milk"
            }
        ]
    }
*/

for(var key in outputObj) {
    outputArr.push({'user': key, 'tasks': outputObj[key]})
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(outputArr, null, 4))
/*
    [
        {
            "user": "123",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "buy milk"
                },
                {
                    "name": "get bread"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user": "456",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "buy milk"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
*/
```

Final output:

```
[
    {
        "user": "123",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "name": "buy milk"
            },
            {
                "name": "get bread"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user": "456",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "name": "buy milk"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```